# How to rewrite git history to match a popular git workflow

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have my most of master branch look like a linked list instead of a tree.  That is, most merges I did were fast-forward merges.  I figured I will follow ["A successful Git branching model"](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) workflow, which instructs me to avoid fast-forward merges and instead leave tracks of my features and feature branch joins.  Suppose it is a good idea.

How do I rework my tree most painlessly?

i.e say I have this kind of log:

```
* hash1 great feature #1 - almost done
* hash2 side work
* hash3 side work
* hash4 great feature #1 - added y
* hash5 great feature #1 - added x
* hash6 documentation - added more docs
* hash7 documentation - removed stuff
* hash8 project-wide:  added deployment descriptors....
```

I want this kind of log (or any similar version):

```
* merged side work into branch develop
|\
* * hash2 (feature branch) side work
* * hash3 (feature branch) side work
|/
*  merged great feature into branch develop
|\ 
* * hash1 (feature branch) great feature #1 - almost done
* * hash4 (feature branch) great feature #1 - added y
* * hash5 (feature branch) great feature #1 - added x
|/ 
* merged documentation into branch develop
|\
| * hash6 (feature branch) documentation - added more docs
| * hash7 (feature branch) documentation - removed stuff
|/
* hash8 project-wide (develop branch):  added deployment descriptors....
```

I have over 40 commits and my tree is a whole lot messier than I have presented here, so creating a new branch from init and cherry-picking individual commits are most painful.  I guess rebase --interactive is where it may help, but then I am not sure if it will.  rebase flattens the tree, and I need to bulk it up.  I have shown merging `feature` branch into `develop`, but I may also at some points merge `develop` branch into `master`.  How?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, first of all you don't have so much commit so you can do is rewriting your history, the problem is that you will have to push --force at the end.

```
git rebase HEAD~40 -i
```

Then here you can **squash** by changing **pick** to **s** (merge 2 commits together) and edit your commits messages by changing **pick** to **e**

Other solution as you said again, an history is just an history you can keep track of your previous "workflow" and start the new one whenever you want. You will keep as it is the real history even if it wasn't perfect.

IMO, squash as much as you can, edit a bit your history, and start your new workflow.

Comment: I am still having some trouble seeing how this will work.  I don't necessarily want to squash commits, but I do want to create new branches out of master branch for features, which I will merge back into master.  During rebase creating a new branch does not seem to do much.  I am just kind of confused. I guess I do need to skip some commits for certain branches, and merge them later.  rebase works for a single branch it seems, or maybe I am using it wrong.

Comment: It almost seems to me that maybe I need to start several rebases, one for each branch and then juggle commits between them, to create this workflow?  If so, maybe I should just move on and leave my git history as is

Comment: You will certainly have to rebase your branches regularly depending on the merge you have done on your master from other branches.

What you can also is **git merge feature/branchA --no-commit --no-ff** review your merge, do some changes or resolve conflict and do your **git commit**